# Возвращение нескольких значений

Tags: java

Можно ли возвратить из метода несколько значений?
Если можно, то напишите как.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Почему бы не хранить значения в массиве или HashMap'е? Допустим

```
private HashMap<String, String> getValuesMap() {
    //ваш код
    HashMap<String, String> tmpHashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    tmpHashMap.put("value1", "значение 1");
    tmpHashMap.put("value2", "значение 2");
    tmpHashMap.put("value3", "значение 3");
    return tmpHashMap;
}
```

Ну, а там, где у вас вызывается этот метод

```
HashMap<String, String> values = getValuesMap();
String str = values.get("value1");
```

Может проще было делать с массивом String[], тут уж вам выбирать

Comment: Ну или можно просто завести класс, класть в него возвращаемые значения, и возвращать экземпляр класса.

Comment: Ещё как вариант - возвращать массив класса *Object*, это если понадобится вернуть несколько значений разных типов.